# Rosbag API and TF transforming tools

Tags: ros, rosbag, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently writing some tools in Python to visually judge the quality of the odometry. For this I record a bag with odom topic as well as tf, lidar scans and wheel encoders.

Then I loop over the bag data, read all poses from odom and project the lidar scans to cartesian coordinates in the odom frame using the odom pose with the **closest timestamp**.

My odom is published at 100 Hz while the lidar scans are published at around 10 Hz so in worst case the time offset will be 5ms.

I then plot all lidar scans for all poses and see how well they overlap (Similar to setting decay_time of lidar scans to a very big value in Rviz)

Here is the result:

[image: image description]

Compared to Rviz (with big decay time)

[image: image description]

I noticed that my plot and the data displayed in Rviz (with a decay time covering all the length of the bag while doing rosbag play) looks slightly different.

Especially when zooming on known features, for example the half circle:

My plot:
[image: image description]

Rviz:
[image: image description]

The difference becomes very clear.

When looking in the source code of Rviz I saw that it just transforms the lidar scan to a pointcloud and then uses TF to transform it to the correct frame.
My question is how to do such a thing without having to play the bag, but only using the rosbag API, on Python? I suspect using the closest timestamp to be the source of error. Does TF interpolate to get the exact pose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259073/rosbag-api-and-tf-transforming-tools/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2017-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I remember correctly, tf does interpolate.

In C++ you could create a tf2::BufferCore and use its [setTransform method](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1BufferCore.html#a8f3900f749ab24dd824b14c0e453d1a6), then query it as usual. Maybe you can do something similar in python?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2017-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2